# What is use of the tagging interface if they are used only for the marking?

Tags: java, interface

Is there any other uses of the tagging interface?

Why they are used if they don't have any body definition ?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

The interfaces with no defined methods act **like markers**. They just tell the compiler that the objects of the classes implementing the interfaces with no defined methods need to be treated differently. Marker interfaces are also known as **tag interfaces** since they tag all the derived classes into a category based on their purpose.

As example:

The `java.io.Serializable` interface, which is only a *marker* interface -- it simply
allows the serialization mechanism to verify that the class can be persisted, typically to a file.